# How to prevent my process from CreateToolhelp32Snapshot?

Tags: windows, winapi

Is there a way to prevent another process from detecting my process by using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot?

Comment: Search for how to write malware

Comment: I'm not interested in writing malware, our application is to help customers do some automation work, however the target application provider doesn't like the idea and keep detecting what executables are running on client's computer.

Comment: only if you create driver, which unlink your process from `PsActiveProcessHead` list

Comment: @user1633272 there is no official API to do what you want. David's comment is not suggesting you should write malware, just study how to write malware. Malware employ all kinds of hacks and low level tricks to try to hide themselves from detection. Learn those tricks. For example, you could use DLL injection to hook `Process32(First|Next)` directly in the target app to make them skip past your process while it is enumerating processes.

Comment: I'm currently using dll injection, the problem with it is that it only works after the target application being injected, but target app could already use actual Process32First before being hooked. If there is no better approach, I might use AppInit_DLLs to do such trick. Thanks @RemyLebeau

Comment: I personally would consider such a program malware, and I'm sure a good anti-malware detection tool would agree. It looks like your target application (the victim) thinks that way too. But as Remy said, what you want to do is done by malware, so that's where to look.

Comment: @user1633272 - You should probably re-do this question with what you are **really trying to do**.  Something about *help customers do automation work*. Open up more on this problem and more technical details about how the target process is blocking your code from doing what it needs to do. That will generate a better set of ideas and answers.

Comment: Avoid using AppInit_DLLs, a better way to inject a DLL into an application is to use the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit to generate a compatibility shim for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a environment where you need to protect users from themselves then these users need to be non-admin users and you can simply create a service or task that runs as a different user so it cannot be killed.

If you absolutely need to hide the process and your chosen method is injection & hooking then there are at least 6 things you need to hook in user-mode:

- The toolhelp API
- The NT4 process API in psapi.dll
- The undocumented native NT API
- The [terminal server API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383831(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Performance counters
- WMI

A "better" solution is to remove your process from the PsActiveProcessHead list but you need to be in kernel-mode to do that and that means writing a custom driver. If you go down this route your program will be labeled as malware/rootkit by some security tools (and rightly so).